# How do I get the links to work in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, href

So I've been tinkering with HTML and CSS for a little bit (please excuse my presentation) and I've been trying to get a fixed navbar working with inpage links that go the different sections within my one page website. I've knocked this up this morning and I can't for the life of me get the links to work.

I've had a google and there's a few similar posts saying that the z-index is the issue but I've had a play about with it and I still can't get them to work.

...anyone fancy shedding some light on it for me?

```css
html {

}

body{
  font-family: 'Nunito';
  background: linear-gradient(#8FB0B7, #E8EFF0);
}

header {
  background-color: #e6763c;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */

}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2.5em;
  background: #DDCFB199;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
/* On hover animations */
li:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 7px #3333;
  transform: scale(1.02);


}
/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  header {
    background-color: #e6763c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 0.2rem;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }

  li {
    display: block;
    margin:   1.2rem;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <title>Original Tombstones</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <h1>Original Tombstones</h1>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#new"></a>New Memorials</li>
    <li><a href="#additionals"></a>Additionals</li>
    <li><a href="#renovations"></a>Renovations</li>
    <li><a href="#contact"></a>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="container" id="home">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="new">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="additionals">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="renovations">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="contact">
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work about them. Does the content not load? Are they not clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your innerHTML is empty inside your `<a>` tags. This worked for me
Put this for your links instead:

```
<li><a href="#new">New Memorials</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text wasn't wrapped in the anchor tag. You have to put the `</a>` tag right before the closing `</li>` tag like so:

```
<header>
  <h1>Original Tombstones</h1>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#new">New Memorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#additionals">Additionals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#renovations">Renovations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text inside the `<a>` tag i.e

instead of :

```html
<li><a href="#renovations"></a>Renovations</li>
```

try

```html
<li><a href="#renovations">Renovations</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Nunito";
  background: linear-gradient(#8fb0b7, #e8eff0);
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999px;
  background-color: #e6763c;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2.5em;
  background: #ddcfb199;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}
/* On hover animations */
li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 7px #3333;
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    background-color: #e6763c;
    padding-left: 0.2rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  li {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>Original Tombstones</h1>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#new">New Memorials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#additionals">Additionals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#renovations">Renovations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="container" id="home">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="new">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="additionals">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="renovations">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container" id="contact">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your links are empty. The text is outside the closing anchor tag `</a>` so they are acting as list items instead of links. Put the text inside the anchor tag.

```html
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="#new">New Memorials</a></li>
<li><a href="#additionals">Additionals</a></li>
<li><a href="#renovations">Renovations</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```